# How to protect my USB drive files from antivirus removal

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

I have recently purchased **Trend Micro Titanium Antivirus** and installed in my PC.

When I connect some virus affected USB, it completely removes all the content of my USB.

How I can save my USB content from removal?

Comment: Remove the virus with some other anti-virus product what you have experienced isn't normal even with Trend Micro.

Answer (score 0):

First, If a Antivirus-Software wouldn't delete/put files in quarantine, than the Antivirus would be useless.

For example, if there is a worm, trojan etc. on your usb-stick, you don't want, that it infects your PC.

But the Titanium Antivirus provides a quarantine-location where you can restore the files which are marked as malicious. If your file is stored there, your can restore it:

> 1. Open Main Console
> 2. Click on Security Summary or Summary Report(right side of the Scan button and beside the wheel like icon)
> 3. Click on view detailed logs
> 4. If you want to restore the file which was quarantined, you can single click on the entry and it would provide an option to restore
>      the file

[Source](http://community.trendmicro.com/t5/Titanium/Quarantine-Location-for-Titanium-Max-Security-2011/td-p/23526)